# Authentication error uploading Images to Imgur

Tags: reactjs, axios, imgur

```
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append("image", uploadedimage);
  console.log(data);
  axios
    .post("https://api.imgur.com/3/image/", data, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Client-ID ${apiKey}`,
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
```

I have this code set up inside of my react app. I can't figure out why I keep getting this authentication error.
{
"data": {
"error": "Authentication required",
"request": "/3/image/",
"method": "GET"
},
"success": false,
"status": 401
}
I know my API-Key and uploaded image is good but for some reason this code is not getting through. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am look at this in the imgur api docs,

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image' \
--header 'Authorization: Client-ID {{clientId}}' \
--form 'image=R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the Axios docs here, not sure if it'll help or not.
[enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

```js
// Set config defaults when creating the instance
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.example.com'
});

// Alter defaults after instance has been created
instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be helping. thanks though.